# How can i Connect Android project to mysql JDBC

Tags: android, mysql

i would like to connect my android project to my db on mysql JDBC.. im using wampserver...  when i run the program i have this error

```
 Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo
 W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'widy-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

this is my code

```
public class Conexion {

    String classs = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sanz";
    String un = "root";
    String password = "Kamasutra,27";
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs).newInstance();

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, password);


            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

if anybody can give me a hand it will be very helpful thank you very much

Comment: @Win Maer using JDBC driver you can not establish a connection with the database you need Webservice for the same.

Comment: thank you very much @KishanDonga

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend for your apps directly talking to a database, You should create a web services api to send and receive data from your mobile apps to web service api.

Comment: thank you for ur answer Fenan.. create a web services sound like .. i must use some php files?

Comment: depends on ur preference but yes you can use php whichever convenient for you.

Comment: what other possibity i have ?